# Azure DevOps Pipelines. Unable to Set Timeout on Task Level

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure documentation states:

> You can also set the timeout for each task individually - see [task
> control options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#controloptions).

Yet, my task still times out despite me following the syntax and using self-hosted agent.
Here is my Pipeline:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: 'DevOps-Agent2-VM'
steps:
- checkout: none

- task: PowerShell@2
  timeoutInMinutes: 5760
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        Write-Host Starting writing log file
        $PathLogFiles = "C:\Logs"
        $DayFileNameLog = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss
        $NewFolderName = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss
        $PathLogFileFull = "$PathLogFiles\PSRemotingLogs-$DayFileNameLog.log"
        Start-Transcript -Path "$PathLogFileFull" -Append

        $Timer = New-Timespan -Hours 96
        $Clock = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
        While ($clock.elapsed -lt $timer){
        Get-Date
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
        }       
        Write-Host Timer end

        Write-Host Stopping writing log file
        Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have place time out under job, then only it'll work for your tasks- see below.

```
trigger:
  - none
resources:
  - repo: self
variables:
  - group: iosvariables
jobs:
  - job: build
    timeoutInMinutes: 180
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macos-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
    - task: NodeTool@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Node'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.8.0' # you can use your desired version here
    - script: yarn install
      displayName: Install Dependencies
    - script: |
        # Disable autocommit on version bump 
        yarn config set version-sign-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-git-tag false
        yarn config set version-commit-hooks false
        Checkout branch where the build is triggered
        git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
        # Extract existing version of package.json
        oldVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Bump version
        yarn version --patch
        # Add bumped version to staging
        git add *
        # Extract new version of package.json
        newVer=$(jq -r ".version" package.json)
        # Set environment variables
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OLD_VERSION]$oldVer"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NEW_VERSION]$newVer"
      displayName: 'Bump version and set variables'

    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: Install Apple Certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'abc.p12'
        certPwd: '$(p12password)'
        keychain: 'temp'
        deleteCert: true
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install Apple Provisioning Profile'
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: 'abc_QA.mobileprovision'
        removeProfile: true
    - task: CocoaPods@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Install CocoaPods'
      inputs:
        workingDirectory: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/abc-xyz/ios'
    - task: Xcode@5
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Build IPA'
      inputs:
        actions: 'build'
        configuration: 'Qa'
        sdk: 'iphoneos'
        scheme: 'abcQa'
        xcWorkspacePath: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/abc-xyz/ios/abcmobile.xcworkspace'
        packageApp: true
        exportPath: 'output/$(SDK)/$(Configuration)'
        exportMethod: 'enterprise'
        signingOption: 'manual'
        signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
        provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
        Contents: |
          **/*.ipa
          **/*.dSYM/**
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        overWrite: true
        cleanTargetFolder: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      timeoutInMinutes: 180
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: iOSBuild'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: iOSBuild
```

Comment: But why would I refactor my code to in addition to tasks also you job, when jobs are not needed for my use case and are overkill, when documentation clearly says: You can also set the timeout for each task individually?

Comment: @WinBoss..Tasks can be set individually for timeout but not above the by default timeout permission of pipeline. i.e default pipeline timeout is 60 min, in this case task can be set to maximum to 60 min not more than that. to increase the whole pipeline default time out we've to set first under job..and this wont affect or add any additional  time run duration to your pipeline. its just simply you're putting your tasks under job, thats it. hope this helps.